# Giving examples of some group $G$ and elements $g,h \in G$ where $(gh)^{n}\neq g^{n} h^{n}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Ok so I know that generally,

$(gh)^{n}$ $\neq$ $g^{n}h^{n}$

because n-times for $(gh)^{n}$ is: $ghghghghghg$.

because n-times for $g^{n} h^{n}$ is $gggggggg hhhhhhhh$.
(My professor made mention though that for abelian this may be true? Why).

(My professor also made mention that for $n=2, 12$ and $13$ will work? Why).
Is it because

$[(12)(13)]^{2}$ = $12^{2}13^{2}$ ? It doesn't follow this problem unless

$12*13*12*13 = 12*12*13*13$?

Is this correct?

Comment: "for abelian this may be true? Why" What makes Abelian groups ... Abelian? What can you do in an Abelian group that you cannot necessarily do in general?

Comment: Did I make the right leap? My professor just spoke this. Is my leap ok .

Answer (score 2):

For $g,h\in G$, if $gh=hg$, then $(gh)^n=g^nh^n$ for all $n\in \Bbb{Z}$.
You can try to verify this using induction.

While if $gh\neq hg$, the result may not hold.
Take $G=S_3$ as example.
$$(12)(13)=(132)$$
Then $$(12)^2(13)^2=1$$
but $$[(12)(13)]^2=(132)^2=(123)$$
Hence $$(12)^2(13)^2\neq [(12)(13)]^2$$

Answer (score 0):

We can take the group $M(2,\mathbb Z)$:

Let be $A=(\array{1&0\\0&2})$ and  $B=(\array{1&0\\1&0})$ then  $AB=(\array{1&0\\2&0})$ and  $(AB)^n=(\array{1&0\\2&0})$

while  $B^n=(\array{1&0\\1&0})$ and  $A^n=(\array{1&0\\0&2^n})$ then  $B^nA^n=(\array{1&0\\1&0})$.

We note that  $(AB)^n\ne B^nA^n$